# Splitsize for the Hive table in TDCH

Tags: hadoop, split, mapreduce, hive, teradata

I'm using TDCH to export a hive data into teradata table. For this I need to specify the number of mappers to my TDCH job. 
So, my question is "is this number of mappers option we give to TDCH job is just a hint to TDCH? or are these total number of mappers created by TDCH will always be equal to number of mappers given in the option (of the TDCH job)"?

My assumption is that the number of mappers mainly depends on the split-size than on the given number of mappers (in the options of TDCH job). Is my assumption correct for the TDCH jobs?.
Also, for the Hive table how is the split size defined? is that defined based on the number of rows? or it's just defined based on the size of the data (like 60MB or 120MB etc) similar to the cases like the "textfiles"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "is this number of mappers option we give to TDCH job is just a hint to TDCH? or are these total number of mappers created by TDCH will always be equal to number of mappers given in the option (of the TDCH job)"?

Splitsize in TDCH is always equals to "number of mappers" specified (I read this in one of the TDCH tutorials). So, number of mappers is not just a hint (unlike in conventional mapreduce programming) it's nothing but the number of splits.

As it's equals to number of splits total number of mappers generated for a TDCH job is always equals to "number of mappers" (option) specified while running the job.